# PayPal Python SDK issue with response

Tags: python, flask, paypal, python-requests

I am attempting to set up the PayPal Python SDK using flask restful. Unfortunately, I am having an issue which hours of work were not able to make progress on.

I have the client and server side code as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#on-the-client).

Here is what my code looks like that calls that:

```
class PayPalOrder(Resource):
    def post(self):
        order = CreateOrder()
        response = order.create_order(debug=True)
        print(response.result.links)
        links = []
        for link in response.result.links:
            links.append({"href":link.href,"rel":link.rel,"method":link.method})
        json_response = {"id":response.result.id,
        "status":response.result.status,
        "links":links}
        print(json_response)
        return jsonify(json_response)

api.add_resource(PayPalOrder, '/api/create-paypal-transaction')
```

Unfortunately, it seems no matter what I try, I get the following error on the webpage:

```
js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2 Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=eyJwYXlwYWwiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWV9LCJjYXJkIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjp0cnVlLCJicmFuZGVkIjp0cnVlLCJ2ZW5kb3JzIjp7InZpc2EiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWV9LCJtYXN0ZXJjYXJkIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjp0cnVlfSwiYW1leCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6dHJ1ZX0sImRpc2NvdmVyIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjp0cnVlfSwiaGlwZXIiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiZWxvIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImpjYiI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9fX0sInZlbm1vIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sIml0YXUiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiY3JlZGl0Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjp0cnVlfSwicGF5bGF0ZXIiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwic2VwYSI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJpZGVhbCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJiYW5jb250YWN0Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImdpcm9wYXkiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiZXBzIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sInNvZm9ydCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJteWJhbmsiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwicDI0Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sInppbXBsZXIiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwid2VjaGF0cGF5Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sInBheXUiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiYmxpayI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJ0cnVzdGx5Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sIm94eG8iOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwibWF4aW1hIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImJvbGV0byI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJtZXJjYWRvcGFnbyI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9fQ==&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101:68347
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101:4827)
    at e.n.resolve (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101:3884)
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101:3528
    at n.e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:10892)
    at n.e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:9949)
    at n.e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:11258)
    at n.e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:9949)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:10759
    at n.e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:10892)

Error: Expected an order id to be passed
    at Bt.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:55485)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:62925)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:62784)
    at $t (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:62937)
    at u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:67977)
    at ur (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:68166)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:73210
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2:73256
Bt.error @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
o @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
$t @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
u.on @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
ur @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
e.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
e.then @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
n.try @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
u @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
trigger @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
n.try @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
On @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
e.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
e.then @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
n.try @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
ar.postrobot_message_request @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
ur @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101 Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed
    at buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101
    at e.n.dispatch (buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101)
    at e.n.resolve (buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101)
    at buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVl4Q2FOVllUQ0NtSDV1NXhzZmhNMGF4VFYtWU5QbHZ2RTFWbVNEYzRRTEpWNm1nTFNHek9wTlhFZlhWY0dwbG90NkJTZkExSVAyLW52YzMiLCJhdHRycyI6e319&clientID=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3&sessionID=644ab16adb_mja6mdg6ntc&buttonSessionID=fc12d459b8_mja6mjg6mdy&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1101
    at n.e.dispatch (js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2)
    at n.e.resolve (js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2)
    at n.e.dispatch (js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2)
    at n.e.resolve (js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2)
    at js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2
    at n.e.dispatch (js?client-id=AYxCaNVYTCCmH5u5xsfhM0axTV-YNPlvvE1VmSDc4QLJV6mgLSGzOpNXEfXVcGplot6BSfA1IP2-nvc3:2)
```

That's quite a block of text so the summary of it is that I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Expected an order id to be passed
```

However, as far as I can tell, I'm passing a response that follows the specifications [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders) under the section titled "Response":

```
{
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "approve",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "update",
      "method": "PATCH"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T/capture",
      "rel": "capture",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

I WAY overcomplicated this. All it needs is JUST the order ID, and the key in the JSON needs to be renamed to `orderID`. The following works:

```
class PayPalOrder(Resource):
    def post(self):
        order = CreateOrder()
        response = order.create_order(debug=True)
        return {"orderID": response.result.id}

api.add_resource(PayPalOrder, '/api/create-paypal-transaction')
```

I'm going to leave this answer because I couldn't find a clear answer on this anywhere, regardless of language or flask. Or I was misunderstanding everything.